# How to create connection with tcp server

Tags: iphone

I need to create a TCP Connection with a server running on device , I need to send the binary data after connection in following format.

```
     Field          Byte        Value
   1: packet id      1           0X01
   2: length         1            2
   3:Buadrate        4       The bit rate in bps used by the can
                             BUS. Maximum value is 1000000.

  4:extended         1       If this is set to one the device will use
                             the extended frame format
```

Please help that how can create tcp connection with server running on 2000 port 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you look into using CocoaAsyncSocket which will ease some of it...

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/Intro

When you have your socket setup you can send (`writeData:`) your data as a C struct, but you might need to have the right *endianess* for the Baudrate. Check that.

Comment: i have create connection with device but i am not getting how to send above data